# Sorting algorithm returning incorrect answer

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, graph, mathematical-optimization

I have a csv with Rows of data. Each row consists of an `amount_of_apples` and a number of `steps`. The amount_of_apples are the total number of apples in a room and the steps is the distance in steps to the room.

```
amount_of_apples, steps
6,  99
9,  45
15, 88
32, 115
6,  52
74, 227
2,  56
17, 14
9,  49
```

I would like to know what is the max number of apples I can collect if I can only travel max_steps a day e.g 100.

My current solution involves sorting the rooms by weight and then visiting each room according to weight.

`weight := numberOfApples / steps`

So I’d go to the room with 59 apples that’s 1 step away first and then the room with 51 apples that’s 3 steps away next. I’d then visit the next room in the list with a number of step smaller than my remaining steps and continue until I run out of rooms or steps.

current solution (returns `26` which is incorrect):

```
// sort rooms by weight ratio of apples to steps
sort.SliceStable(rooms, func(i, j int) bool {
        currRatio := rooms[i].numberOfApples/ rooms[i].steps
        nextRatio := rooms[j].numberOfApples / rooms[i].steps
        return currRatio > nextRatio
    })

var results []Room
    var index int
    var count float64
    var steps int
    for steps < maxSteps {
     step += rooms[index].steps
        if steps > maxSteps {
            break
        }
        results = append(results, rooms[index])
        count += rooms[index].numberOfApples
        index += 1
    }

log.Printf("The max number of apples that can be collected in %vsteps is %v", maxSteps, count)
```

However, I do not think this is the correct solution.

P.S we can assume that once a room is visited and apples are collected you magically teleport back to the starting point. So no steps are wasted backtracking.

Comment: Sounds like a graph problem, not a sorting problem.

Comment: This should be a graph problem, if you want it to represent a real scenario (and in that case, your number of steps changes depending on each room you visit; you'd need to represent the problem as a graph). As described, it can expressed as a mathematical optimization. Basically, you want to maximize sum(apples); this is your utility function. In addition, you have the constraint that steps <=100. You can try asking the question at math.stackexchange.com if you want a better answer.

Comment: @jarmod and cabad, why would you assume that the problem is different than stated so that you can make it into a graph problem?

Comment: This has all needed details, and is a dynamic programming problem. WHY WAS IT CLOSED?? You just need the idea of an "optimal fringe" to solve it. Meaning after deciding whether to visit each room we only keep track of partial solutions that find more apples than any solution with less steps (and only 1 solution per # of steps). The algorithm is `O(rooms * steps)`.

Comment: Since I can't answer, I'll just do it in comments. Start with finding 0 apples in 0 steps. For each room, we take the previous optimal fringe (sorted on # of steps), and produce a new set of solutions (visit current room).  We then merge those to find the new optimal fringe. After the last room, the point on the fringe with the most steps is your best possible answer. Bonus, each solution at each step is a linked list, so only `O(1)` of new data. For `O(steps)` memory, `O(rooms * steps)` time.

Comment: Propose that the OP updates the question to include an expected result (currently doesn't indicate what the result is, or why it's wrong, or what the expected result is), and also explains how steps are to be counted when moving from one room to another room (does the walker return N steps to some central point and then M steps forward to another room, for example).

Comment: Yup, I agree with @btilly, the question has sufficient details. However, I've added the requested information so it can be reopened.

Comment: @Osaro Actually your algorithm returns the correct answer for that example. Add 2 rooms with 6 apples at 40 steps and your algorithm still says 26 while the real answer is 29.

Comment: sorry, could you please clarify? I don't understand. There are no rooms with 40 steps in that example. Also apples can only be taken from a room once. Also the maxSteps in the case above is 100

Comment: @Osaro I'm saying that the answer your code produces in that example was correct. The best you can do is 26 apples.  But with 2 more lines of data you would get an example where your code produces a wrong answer.

Comment: @jarmod Note that https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984102/585411 is my answer to a slightly harder version of the same exact problem today. Yes it is amounts and delays instead of apples and steps, but it is the same problem.  And it ISN'T "graph theory" OR something that math.stackexchange.com is likely to give a good answer to.

Comment: Check out [revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72971706/6), too.

Answer (score 0):

This got reopened, so I might as well see what it is like to program in golang.

This just returns the maximum number, and not which rooms you visited.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984102/585411 for how to find the rooms.

```
func findMaxApples(maxSteps int, rooms []Room) int {
        // We will use "fake rooms to indicate the results of our trip.
        fringe := []Room{
                {
                        steps:          0,
                        numberOfApples: 0,
                },
        }

        for _, room := range rooms {
                withRoom := []Room{}
                for _, prevPath := range fringe {
                        if prevPath.steps+room.steps <= maxSteps {
                                withRoom = append(withRoom, Room{steps: prevPath.steps + room.steps, numberOfApples: prevPath.numberOfApples + room.numberOfApples})
                        }
                }
                
                newFringe := []Room{}
                i := 0
                j := 0 
                for (i < len(fringe)) && (j < len(withRoom)) {
                        chooseFringe := false
                        if fringe[i].steps < withRoom[j].steps {
                                chooseFringe = true 
                        } else if withRoom[j].steps < fringe[i].steps {
                                chooseFringe = false
                        } else if fringe[i].numberOfApples < withRoom[j].numberOfApples {
                                chooseFringe = false
                        } else {
                                chooseFringe = true
                        }
                        
                        if chooseFringe {
                                for j < len(withRoom) && withRoom[j].numberOfApples <= fringe[i].numberOfApples {
                                        j++
                                }
                                newFringe = append(newFringe, fringe[i])
                                i++
                        } else {
                                for i < len(fringe) && fringe[i].numberOfApples <= withRoom[j].numberOfApples {
                                        i++
                                }
                                newFringe = append(newFringe, withRoom[j])
                                j++
                        }
                }
               
                for i < len(fringe) {
                        newFringe = append(newFringe, fringe[i])
                        i++
                }

                for j < len(withRoom) {
                        newFringe = append(newFringe, withRoom[j])
                        j++
                }

                fringe = newFringe
        }

        return fringe[len(fringe)-1].numberOfApples
}
```